# How to realize multi-monitor setting changes with winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screen

**Background:**
I often find the task of configuring my dual monitors to either extend or display on a single monitor quite cumbersome. I am seeking a more efficient and user-friendly solution for this.

**Request:**
I have a couple of specific requirements for this task:

1. I would like to create a button that allows me to easily switch between different multi-monitor display modes.
2. My primary monitor (screen 1) has a resolution of 1920x1080 and is set to landscape mode. The secondary monitor (screen 2) has a resolution of 2160x3840 and is set to portrait mode.
3. Screen 1 should be positioned on the left side, and screen 2 on the right side, both with their top edges aligned at position 0.

**My Code:**

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    int displayIndex = 0;

    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, displayIndex, &dd, 0)) {
        if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE) {
            DEVMODE devMode;
            devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
            EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode);
            devMode.dmPelsWidth = 1920; 
            devMode.dmPelsHeight = 1080; 
            ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(dd.DeviceName, &devMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);
        }
        displayIndex++;
    }

    // 设置第二个显示器分辨率
    DEVMODE devMode2;
    devMode2.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    devMode2.dmPelsWidth = 2160;
    devMode2.dmPelsHeight = 3840;
    ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(dd.DeviceName, &devMode2, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);

    // 设置显示模式为拓展模式
    DEVMODE devModeExt;
    devModeExt.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    devModeExt.dmFields = DM_POSITION;
    devModeExt.dmPosition.x = 1920; // 第二个显示器的横坐标，设置为第一个显示器的宽度
    devModeExt.dmPosition.y = 0; // 第二个显示器的纵坐标
    ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, &devModeExt, NULL, CDS_SET_PRIMARY | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Any corrections, suggestions, or guidance to make this process smoother and more efficient?

Comment: So does your code work?

Comment: You could put this cumbersome code in a function and call it from your code. That would be much better then just dumping it all in your `int main()`